# ★ A better name for our site ★

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed

Currently our question header states

> ## WORDPRESS ANSWERS

but in our FAQ, filed under "How to ask", we can find the following ***important*** bit of text:

> What topics can I ask about here?
>
> WordPress Stack Exchange is for WordPress **developers and administrators** to ask questions about:
>
> - theme and plugin development
> - development and management best practices
> - server configuration for WordPress

---

## A new name

It's clear and fully agreed between all constantly participating people on the site, that we need a new name.

***Let's rename it!***

## How it works:

Answer with: Name idea

- One suggestion per answer
- Format as heading (prefix with a single `#`)
- +1/-1 vote/downvote those you like/dislike

### *[Optional] Tagline that goes with the name*

Format as subheading. If you only got a tagline suggestion, please briefly note that.

Comment: Can we please just take "WordPress Answers" out to the backyard and shoot it...

Comment: Fully support that.

Comment: Jquery_poommerce would fit better.

Comment: This Unicode title may set dangerous precedents, beautiful :) There's a similar thread going on at MSO: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/202476

Comment: I'm not seeing an obvious disconnect between the current name and the site's scope. Is the current name causing problems that you're hoping to solve with a renaming?

Comment: Maybe peruse the overall question quality, as well as the non-trivial amount of questions that get closed due to being off-topic. "WordPress Answers" simply does not convey sufficiently that the site is intended for **developers and administrators**, asking appropriately scoped questions.

Comment: @AnnaLear I wouldn't quite _blame_ name for anything, but this issue has long history of dissatisfaction with name, stemming from it being _temporary_ placeholder (community had no say in) that got permanent when custom name/domain program was scrapped. People hadn't chosen it, people don't like it, people don't use it (WPSE is almost universally used to refer to the site).

Comment: @AnnaLear wp.com questions and plugin/theme recommendations are off topic. A better name could communicate that better. Especially since there is no usable FAQ page anymore.

Comment: Related: [Hidden on topic page](http://meta.wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/2503/hidden-on-topic-page). On some days, we have to close every third or forth question now. A better name wouldn’t fix that completely, but we have to do _something_ to get out of this situation.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Just throwing it out there:

## WordPress Development

Comment: Simple, Clean, Straightforward, Honest... I'd support that.

Comment: Of course this is what I want to see most. I'm not marking it as solution yet, as I hope someone from SE will jump in and tell us that they ***fix*** it.

Comment: Oh, I like that! The implicit message, _don’t ask for links!_, is just a nice side-effect. :)

Comment: Signing in for this one. +1 Me too!

Comment: w19t - great idea, I support this 100%

Comment: Excellentofantabuolousiyosso! Are you listening? :)

Comment: I would change it to "WordPress Developers" since the site is really about people.

Comment: @wyck propose as separate answer

Comment: @Wyck when you do, count me in for a +1.

Comment: OK done, though not sure it warranted a new post.

Comment: I think its important to include administration :-/

Answer (score 22):

Name for the site

### WordPress Developers

Answer (score 16):

*Tagline*

**wp_get_answers()**

- this tagline would only really make sense to WP devs/admins in the first place

Comment: or: `_not_doing_it_wrong()` :)

Answer (score 10):

*Tagline*

#### WordPress StackExchange - for Developers and Administrators

<sup>*In combination with the **WPSE** headline*</sup>

Comment: ...but this, I like.

Answer (score 10):

**EDIT: 12/06 -** Unfortunately, after broader internal discussions, we've concluded that changing the name to "Wordpress Development" will solve some problems, but cause other new ones.

I've [posted a new question](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3714/site-name-the-unfortunate-sequel) laying out our concerns, and opening a new discussion designed to build consensus out exactly what we need to convey, so we can keep working toward a better solution that the current one.

---

**EDIT: 11/18 -** We've asked our in-house designer to change this site's theme to be [WordPress Development](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2631/35055).  Not only did it win the voting here by a landslide, it's the best of the bunch from the reasoning I laid out below.

A few notes:

- Our designer is very busy, so there's no timeline on this change.  (One of the things he's doing is interviewing more designer candidates!)
- The Stack Exchange philosophy has no problem (even encourages) screening content.  But we are not interested in having sites that screens people.  I, for one, am convinced that "Development" is inclusive enough when applied to this site, so it's not a huge concern at the moment.
- If it's not obvious already, we are pretty conservative when it comes to established names.  But we are more than willing to [make changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207404/standardizing-simplifying-se-site-names) when it makes sense.

---

The [Community Team](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99338/who-are-the-community-managers-and-what-do-they-do/99341#99341) looked over this proposal today and we have a few things we'd like you to keep in mind as you brainstorm a name change:

- We are very reluctant to change site names unless the new name is a clear winner over the existing name.  (This has caused me [some embarrassment](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/667/68). ;-)  Frankly, we'd like to avoid name changes if at all possible and cetainly not go down the path of changing names regularly.  So make this opportunity count.
- We all agree that the "X Answers" site name formula is far less than ideal.  The only reason we have [used that in the past](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2640/35055) is to avoid brand confusion.  This works both ways: we don't want the owner of the brand to feel like we are infringing on their legal rights, but we also don't want to confuse people into thinking that this site is somehow a part of the WordPress brand.
- For that reason WordPress—Stack Exchange isn't viable.  But when I think of this site, that's pretty much how I always phrase it in my mind.  I never think of it as WordPress Answers.  I doubt that whatever new name is decided upon will change that perception.
- The names WordPress Developers and WordPress Professionals are problematic because they define the *people* who are welcome at the site rather than the *topic*.  It's fine to design the site "for WordPress developers and administrators", but we don't want to be in the business of checking credentials at the door.
- WordPress Development would be better, but it excludes Administration, which is part of [the topic-space](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).  (WordPress Development & Administration is too much a mouthful, by the way.  We've changed our minds on allowing such names since the naming of Programming Puzzles & Code Golf and the like.)  If there were a suggestions that encompassed both activities, it's more likely to be a clear win.
- We talked about the unique scope issues of this site:

  - It is more closely associated to Stack Overflow (rather than, say, Super User), so it has a strong developer culture.  But it's not purely a developer site or it would be more at home as a tag on Stack Overflow.  This is poorly understood even by Stack Overflow users.
  - For the most part WordPress.com sites are off-topic to the surprise of many.
  - The open source platform is used by a [huge number of sites](http://wordpress.org/showcase/), but not many people are aware of it outside of the blog space.  (I was surprised to know how many sites use the software.)  Building and maintaining these sites turns out to be a much bigger topic than most people (even technical people) are aware of.

  These issues mean that lots of people ask questions on the site without really understanding what's expected here.  Changing the name might help, but it won't be a silver bullet.  (No matter what, it's still going to be the WordPress Q&A site to most people who wind up here.)  Addressing the issue of people asking off topic questions is a different topic.

### Summary

We're fine with changing the name of the site, but none of the names proposed so far are enough of a win to warrant a name change.  If you come up with a name that doesn't unnecessarily cut off participation or artificially limit the scope, we'll be happy to consider it.

Comment: Pretty much all of the active WPSE users are *developers*, have expertise in *development*, and an interest/desire to answer *development* questions. We aren't *administrators* - though administration is a reasonable subset of development. Whether as originally intended or not, WPSE is a WordPress **development** stack. Part of the problem is that the rest of the SE network doesn't realize it. Until recently, the SO WordPress tag wiki actually indicated that WPSE handled **non programming** WordPress questions. That perception is a problem, and one that is adversely impacting WPSE.

Comment: _WordPress Development & Administration is too much a mouthful_ … well, it is not worse than _Programming Puzzles & Code Golf_, _Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair_ or _Software Quality Assurance & Testing_. Not elegant, but probably acceptable.

Comment: @ChipBennett: What would you think of WordPress Stack or WordPress Platform?

Comment: @toscho: Heh.  Those (and English Language & Usage and Gardening & Landscaping, etc.) came before my time, so I don't really know the arguments for them.  I wouldn't be in favor of those names myself.  We've rather soured on 3+ word names lately.

Comment: Development sounds very much like a place noun, in other words is denotes a place to go for "development". Developers on the other hand makes it more a "people" noun, since that is who you are you engaging when you come to WSPE. Your post is a bit strange when you say things like "not many people are aware of it outside of the blog space". http://en.wordpress.com/stats/

Comment: @Wyck: What I mean is that WordPress in the minds of many people means the WordPress.com blogs you linked to.  Not as many people are aware that the platform can and often is used for non-blog sites.  In fact, I didn't know that until today.

Comment: A vote for WordPress Platform here

Comment: I actually pasted the wrong link, it's common for people to not understand that WordPress is not just a blog engine, thus this particular thread. If you browse the questions and answers on WPSE you will see it's developers from the top down.

Comment: While administration is on topic and personally I think it can have great questions, in practice it is insignificantly small proportion of the site. Development is bulk by far. I like "WordPress Stack" but for the record the name have been used before ( https://github.com/markjaquith/WP-Stack ). Dislike "WordPress Platform".

Comment: btw I am not sure about being "spun off" from SO. We have different expert user base (more so at start with people joining WPSE _because_ it wasn't SO) and SO explicitly refused to give up WP as their in scope topic. We never been close to it in my perception.

Comment: "*Not as many people are aware that the platform can and often is used for non-blog sites.*" - The active WPSE contributors, and the people who ask the kinds of questions WPSE seeks, *do* know what WordPress is. One can reasonably infer from this comment that people who don't even know what WordPress *is* are trying to dictate what WPSE should be, to those of us who *do* know.

Comment: @ChipBennett: Absolutely.  That's why we encourage you to continue brainstorming ideas.  Your suggestion is really great except that Administration is clearly in scope (even if it is a small part of the site).

Comment: @JonEricson but should we sacrifice *good* for the sake of the *best* - or, sacrifice *better* for the sake of *perfect*? If **WordPress Developers** encapsulates 99% of our scope (and it *does*), then it should be considered as a valid site name/title on its own merits.

Comment: Should a title be required to define everything that is in scope? I don't see anything wrong with choosing a title that covers 90%+ of the scope, like WordPress Developers does. Focusing on the "people" is hardly a drawback, we are a community of people after all. Nor does it require checking any "credentials". If you are trying to make some kind of adjustment to WP yourself, then you are "doing development", even if you've never touched a line of code before.  A lack of experience doesn't make you not a developer, it just makes you a "rookie" developer.

Comment: "WordPress Development" doesn't necessarily exclude Administration questions, since a site admin is essentially developing their own site.  However, the name may scare off people asking casual, non-technical questions about their WordPress.com blog, and that would be a good thing.

Comment: To be honest I'm a bit puzzled how this site - or any other in the network for that matter - can not be about people. Of course there are distinct scopes of topics, but for whom, if not people. Just saying, regardless of the fact that I like »WordPress Development« better.

Comment: @ialocin: It's absolutely true that this site, like all others on the Stack Exchange network, is about people.  We want to attract expert WordPress Developers.  But we also want to avoid judging _people_ rather than _content_.  Several sites have fallen into the trap of defining their scope on whether the asker is a "professional" or has achieved a certain level of competence.  We want our titles to accurately describe the content of a site without being exclusive of people who have not yet achieved mastery of the topic.

Comment: I wasn't doubting that this is about people, but I exaggerated my point a bit. I'm all for not judging people. But there is no way out of judging, by there content in relation to the defined scope. That was my point, *you can't separate people and topic*, those have to get in tune with each other. Isn't this what the discussion is about, because a new name won't change anything, it's just a way to additionally reflect the WPSE scope as a narrowed topic. Or, to be more specific, to differentiate WPSE from all those general WP related forums and q&a's. At least that's what I'm getting out of it.

Answer (score 8):

Tagline:

#### *You* Code it, we'll help fix it

Comment: Doesn't get my upvote. Just because there's this one bit in there that makes it "not that smooth". Some variation of it? Yes, sure.

Comment: It's more of an inside joke than a sincere submission.

Comment: Well, so far your joke became the most upvoted tagline :D

Comment: I figured that's just because people *got the joke* ;)

Answer (score 7):

## The Loop

*hey, we have loopchat already, why not just make it whole stack? props @brasofilo for thinking of stretching it out*

Comment: +1 Question still is if we want to _completely_ rename it.

Comment: I  think we are having quite a bit of trouble coming up with "WordPress Something", Development is leader however higher powers not high on it so far

Comment: @kaiser, I think of the Stacks that are `Cool Site Name (topic)`

Comment: valid arguments :)

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see this fit as site name. Right, there's _The Loop_ involved in WordPress - deeply involved, if you will. However, it is not just WordPress that is using this/a loop. And WordPress is by far not the pioneer of (ab-)using loops. Also, if you think _The Loop_ appropriate just because WordPress has one, then _Questions_, _Answers_, _PHP_, _Functions_ and the like are all valid possible site names, too. I bet you wouldn't want any of it, though. I hope you get what I wanted to say here... ;)

Comment: @tf this is not about it simply being a thing in WordPress terminology, it's about it being already established name in site's lore and daily life as our main chat room

Comment: And you think that someone, who does not know that name - who is not part of the _established_ community - will understand this? Our highest _demand_ at (new) questions is: they have to be specific to WordPress. Specific. And our site's name shall be something as generic as _The Loop_?

Comment: @tf you have issue with it? down vote it :)

Comment: I did. I thought it couldn't hurt to _explain_ my down-vote with a few words, though. :)

Comment: but there is http://www.loopinsight.com ("the loop")

Answer (score 6):

**When the Codex isn't enough**

- an idea for a tagline – nothing against the amount of info on the Codex!

(Again, just [splitting up my submission](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/users/385/kaiser)).

Comment: +1 I'd just get rid of the _the_ in front of Codex.

Comment: I made a comment about the codex not being enough on a post here, and got my head basically ripped off.

Answer (score 4):

*Name for the site*

## WPSE

*As this is what people commonly refer to*

Comment: I'm not a big fan of Recursive names, in which the acronym is the name.

Comment: Not wooooow-great, but long standing and very practical.

Answer (score 3):

*Name for the site*

## WordPress Exchange

Comment: Like! Less wordy/trademarkish form of Stack Exchange and it still fits. However there is http://ithemes.com/exchange/

Comment: WPF Trademark issues with this one, perhaps?

Answer (score 3):

## WordPress Mania

the platform for WordPress enthusiasts

Answer (score 2):

*Tagline*

### not dot org

<sup>This is just a filler so I can submit this glorious piece of word bits</sup>

Comment: perfect tagline!

Answer (score 2):

## Beyond Codex

................

Comment: Maybe to generic like The Loop, but something. I'm still for WordPress Development

Comment: If _Beyond Codex_ would be the tagline, I'd love it. Got my upvote.

Comment: The current Codex might be replaced eventually. This tag line/title wouldn’t make much sense then.

Answer (score 1):

*Tagline*

### Assistance and Best Practices for Core, Theme, and Plugin Developers

or

### Assistance and Best Practices for the WordPress Platform

Comment: Core is in scope too...

Comment: Is there a single word that incorporates Core, Theme, and Plugin?  "Platform", perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

*Tagline:*

**Assistance and Best Practices for WordPress Developers and Administrators**

or

**Assistance and Best Practices for Developers and Administrators**

---

This is an adaptation from @mantis [proposal](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2643/22534), which I like because it makes inherently clearer what WPSE is about »assistance and best practice«. By adapting it this way I'm having several things in mind: firstly, I'm seeing this as addition to »Wordpress Development«; secondly, this aggregates the »topic-people«-relation; thirdly, it gives an opportunity to include »Developers and Administrators«, without bloating the site name.

Answer (score 0):

## WordPress Stack

.............

Comment: It doesn't have the same ring as WPSE or WP StackExchange.

Comment: WPF Trademark issues with this one, perhaps?

Comment: No more than with others "WordPress *" I would think? And we can always shorten any variation of such to "WP *" to make any trademark issue go away.

Comment: I'm not proposing it, but I would really love to steal ***The Loop*** (it was your idea, wasn't it?). Heck, it's a movie title!

Comment: @brasofilo why aren't you proposing it? try, it just might click with people :)

Comment: @brasofilo I just went ahead and added it, vote up :)

Answer (score 0):

I miss in all this nice answers:

## Debugging WordPress

Yes, we will will also give answers to questions, like a teacher. But the most questions are search for helps on bugs, help to debugging.

Answer (score -2):

### Fix Your WordPress Mess For Less

Comment: This _could_ go as tagline (if we need one, that is), but it's not a candidate for the site's name, IMO.

Comment: @tf :) Just wanted to add my bit of snark into the pot here. :D

Answer (score -2):

**WordMess Busters**

As in 'who you gona call? WordMess Busters!'

Comment: nice one. not voting it up, but I like it.

Answer (score -2):

## WordPress Power - The Must Use Site For All WordPress Administrators

Answer (score -3):

*Name for the site*

## WordPress Professionals

Comment: -1 because not everyone (or even most) are WordPress *professionals*.

Comment: Agree. Still leaving it in here so it doesn't get added a second time.

Comment: Gets my vote. This place should be for professionals by professionals. End-users belong in the WP support forums.

Answer (score -4):

## WordPress Tech

...................

Comment: Personally I think it sucks, but just trying to brainstorm something that conveys *we want technical questions about development and administration*.

Answer (score -5):

*Tagline*

#### Research, Ask, Get professional problem solving Assistance

Comment: +1 for the irony.

Answer (score -5):

## WordPress Platform

.............

Answer (score -5):

**Wordpress**

Couldn't be simpler
- doesn't exclude any activities like management, config, security etc

Answer (score -5):

## Woo Answers

Because paying for support is simply unthinkable

Comment: +1 Amazing answer.

Answer (score -6):

## WordPress DevOps

Includes development and operations. Close enough.

Comment: As mentioned in chat refers to specific methodology rather than generic development and too buzzword.

Answer (score -6):

*Name for the site*

## WordPress Knowledge Exchange

Answer (score -11):

## Copy & Paste WordPress Programming

Because we know what you are really doing.

Sorry. Couldn't resist.

Comment: Funny! Here, have a downvote. :P

Comment: Alternately: **WordPress CopyPasta**

Comment: EPIC. ROFL COPTER!