# My question is on hold

Tags: discussion

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/137350/buddypress-get-activity-meta-along-with-query

Hello, this question went on hold.
Can I ask why? I think its directly related to wordpress, since if I wanted to hack it with my own query, I would do so.

Instead I'm asking for wordpress style solution get get metas along with activity. in case of wordpress this would be posts with post_meta but buddypress.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it was me putting it *on hold*, I'll try to explain. Basically all questions about third party plugins and themes are off topic as you can read in the close reason:

> "Your question should be specific to WordPress. Generic PHP/JS/HTML/CSS questions might be better asked at Stack Overflow or another appropriate site of the Stack Exchange network. Third party plugins and themes are off topic."

Point is, that we can't start trying to [fill the gaps](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3697/our-wooes-and-future-of-platform-plugins-at-wpse) that the lack of support or (lack of easy to use) support routes have opened.

When I read your question, I got to the following point:

> Of course I could made my own query but that feels hacky. Maybe there is no such easy way but you know some workaround?

This left me with the feeling that you don't want to go the native way. Aside from that, we would need to see the source of the meta data wrappers used in BuddyPress. Else we are left with searching for the BuddyPress (or any other plugins or themes) repository, find that function, read through that and all related code and try to wrap our heads around how this is integrated into WP. And that is slightly too much to ask and normally won't get any answer at all due to the amount of work(!) needed to just get around what exactly you were asking. Then there was the lack of effort to try this in a native WP way, which made getting into even harder.

And finally there's the problem that we got close to no BuddyPress experts that are active on this site.

Keep in mind that "on hold" just means:

> "Please go and rework your question to bring it on topic."

When you have done that, just cast a reopen vote. If people agree that your edit brought it back on topic, then it will be brought back to live.

Comment: thanks, I'll try to come up with full and every information one would need, or delete it.

Comment: BuddyPress is NOT a third party plugin. If all plugins and themes are out of scope, then change the FAQs.

Comment: @anu If you got that opinion, please open a new meta question about bringing it into scope again.